# Datagridview checkboxes lose checks

Tags: winforms, checkbox, datagridview

In my Winforms app, I have a form that contains a datagridview with a checkbox column. If I check one or more checkbox items, then make a change to some other control on the form (outside of the datagridview), the checkboxes become unchecked.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

More details: The underlying binding for the checked items is working correctly, as the values are being stored and the checked states are correct when the form reloads. This is just a visual issue.

Furthermore, the checkbox value is never programmatically set to false in the code. False values only come from the binding or from being manually unchecked.

Comment: Without code, it is impossible to answer this.  No clue what you're doing.

Comment: `This is just a visual issue.`  Probably not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redesigned the binding and now it works fine. Was previously maintaining a list of selections in the business object and checking checkboxes based on the selections. Now maintaining a "selected" property in the business object and binding appropriately.

Problem manifested as described due to nature of events generated by checkbox editing (apparently). Binding source change event not triggered when clicking the checkbox (since it was not bound) - only occurred after editing complete on another control.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do an "Invalidate()" on the column to see if a redraw changes anything? Without code, we need to divide the problem arbitrarily.

Comment: Answers usually don't have question marks in them.  This should probably be a comment.